# Автоматизация для ботов в Telegram на Python

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Хочу написать скрипт или программу на Python которая шлёт специальные сообщения боту с каким-то интервалом

Модуль Telethon немного непонятен, Telebot и другие модули непосредственно для написания ботов не подходят. Какие есть другие библиотеки со схожим функционалом?

Comment: Не существует единственного и универсального чудо-модуля, который одной инструкцией выполнял бы Вашу задачу. Берите `telebot`, `shedule` и _программируйте_ решение. Отправку сообщений на `telebot`, задачи на `shedule`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте библиотеку [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot). В ней есть классы Job и JobQueue, с их помощью легко реализовать требуемый функционал.
Пример:

```py
job_queue = updater.job_queue # Инициализация очереди задач
job_queue.put(Job(myfunc, 60.0), next_t=0) # Функция myfunc будет выполняться раз в 60 секунд.
```

Существуют множество параметров для конфигурации задач. Подробнее в [документации](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.job.html)